# Flutter android device id issue

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter, deviceid

Normally it would be pretty easy to get the device id, so I can also use FCM from firebase. This id you need to be able to use their api. So I am able to get the device id (udid), but it seems that this code is much different from what I am getting in java. So I am wondering if I am missing something here and how do I get the correct id.

At the moment I am using the following plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_udid

This is the id in java/android cY_J7681tBA:APA91bGxonHmdY54v3QfI43d_mrz4iRyIDdis2DhUSR4fwOxqkkoNNln1RY4w_yseACBgFTXgHIzknU6KFwhiBf5iMLubRLRuxmVLVsc3P6qhJgkB6IM2FRBTcMRHoyREIrj3fNLq_dY

this is the one i get with the flutter plugin 70afdc2f98b4968db0b7bf64a14aa7156af2f89869dad2db92c6c2d5eec996c9

Both keys are from the android emulator.

I can hardly believe this is the correct id to get in Flutter.

Can anyone tell if this id is still correct or how I should fetch one that is the proper id.

Comment: Did you not get FCM to work?

Comment: Well, I have not yet gotten to that part as I am using the sending api from my server. So at an earlier point, I am getting the device id to store in the database. But I noticed the length difference in ids. So that made me wonder if this is the correct id.